# Equivalences of weak convergence in $\mathcal{L}_p$ spaces with the Lebesgue measure

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega =(0,1)$, and $f,f_n\in \mathcal{L}_p(\lambda)$.

Prove that if $\sup_n{\| f_n \|}<\infty$ and
$$\int_{(0,t]}f_n \, \,\mathrm{d}\lambda\rightarrow \int_{(0,t]}f \, \,\mathrm{d}\lambda,$$

for all $t\in(0,1)$, then 
$$\int_{E}f_n \, \,\mathrm{d}\lambda\rightarrow \int_{E}f \, \,\mathrm{d}\lambda,$$
for all $E$ in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra for $(0,1).$

And that this in turn implies $f_n \rightarrow f$ in the weak topology; i.e. for all $g\in \mathcal{L}_q$,

$$\int_\Omega g f_n \, \,\mathrm{d}\lambda\rightarrow \int_{\Omega}gf \, \,\mathrm{d}\lambda.$$

For the first part I was thinking of using the regularity of $\lambda$ to approximate $E$ by intervals $(0,t]$ but I don't know how to proceed, or even if I'm on the right track (I haven't dealt with the Lebesgue measure in a long time).

Edit: I got the second part already, approximating $g$ by a simple function and using the hypothesis on the converging of integrals for measurable sets. It is only the first part that I don't know how to attack.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use that $\chi_{(a,b]} = \chi_{(0,b]} - \chi_{(0,a]}$ for $a<b$. This will show that your first assumption yields

$$
\int f_n \cdot \chi_{(a,b]} \to \int f \cdot \chi_{(a,b]}
$$
for all $a<b$. By linearity, we get the same convergence for arbitrary Riemann step functions, i.e. for step functions with respect to intervals.

Now, one possibility is to use that $C_c ((0,1))$ is dense in $L^p ((0,1))$ and that you can approximate each function $f \in C_c$ **uniformly** (and hence also in $L^p$) by Riemann step functions as above.

Then conclude the proof by density as you did for the second claim.